# Running test with Spring. --> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring

I'm having problems running a test case which returns `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`. I have already checked for the `@ContextConfiguration` but it looks right.

CLASSES:

```
public class MainSecurityInit extends SecurityFunctionalityCbosInit
{

    protected FileWriter logFile = null;
    private String logFileName = "";

    /* _______________________ Initializers ________________________ */
    @Autowired
    private CbosSecurityInit cbosSecurityInit;

    public void doTest()
    {

        Map<Class, Object> map = new HashMap<Class, Object>();
        List<DataBaseInitializerResult> results = null;

        initLogFile();
        try
        {
            // -------------- Begin of initialization ------------------ //
            cbosSecurityInit.execute();
            // -------------- End of initialization -------------------- //
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            test(results);
        }
        finally
        {
            closeLogFile();
        }

    }
}
```

In the `SecurityFunctionalityCbosInit` the annotations are these:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "security-functionality-cbos-context.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional
public abstract class SecurityFunctionalityCbosInit extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
    //
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:203)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:130)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public void com.arcadia.security.MainSecurityInit.doTest()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$2.doWith(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:466)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:199)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no setter for the property you are going to autowire (`cbosSecurityInit`). In stacktrace, there is a cause message: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public void.

Comment: I have this in the xml. And the path is the right.
<bean id="cbosSecurityInit" class="com.arcadia.security.init.cbos.CbosSecurityInit" />

Comment: There is no setter for ``cbosSecurityInit`` in ``MainSecurityInit`` class. Create ``setCbosSecurityInit(CbosSecurityInit)`` in ``MainSecurityInit`` class.

Comment: Fixed. There was an @Autowired with the instance commented. After comment annotation as well it works. thanks all!!